# SQL Server query to display options values and count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

My SQL Server query looks like the following:

```
SELECT OrderId, Productcode, Quantity, ProductName, options 
FROM OrderDetails 
ORDER BY Productcode DESC
```

which outputs the following results: [image: (please check this image)].

```
There is a table for Options with the following fields and data types
optionsdesc(nvarchar) , id(float)
```

I want to modify the query such that its results contain one column `option` and and second has the quantity sold for that particular option and third order is comma separated like below.. the results should show like below . `Options field is nvarchar(255)`

```
options                           Count      Order id   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Size 15ml bottlle ]                 3          1296,1341, 1384
[Nicotine Level:12 mg Nicotnie ]     2          1296,1312
[Size 30ml bottlle ]                 4          1312,1334, 1344, 1391
```

Comment: This is going to be MUCH easier to do in the app/report/whatever is processing the data versus SQL.

Comment: You don't have a separated table with all options for every order detail ?

Comment: Which version of SQL (2005, 2008, 2012?)

Comment: @Sparky I am using SQL 2005

Comment: ... Your example shows that `OrderDetails .options` column has these options concatenated.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean i have options table with optionsdesc , id where optiondesc are the actual options

Comment: Then, please add this table to your question including, also, the relationship between `OrderDetails` and `OptionDesc` tables.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean added options table details

Comment: @user580950: "...  including, also, the relationship between OrderDetails and OptionDesc tables".

Comment: @BogdanSahlean there is no relation between the 2 tables

Comment: How do you know what options are available for every order detail ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean it just gets displayed in the options column in OrderDetails  table

Comment: You should add another table (ex. `OrderDetailsOptions` if they are different options for every detail) which will link those tables: `OrderDetails` and `Options`. `OrderDetailsOptions` should have following columns: `OrderDetailsID`, `OptionID`.  **Note:** Please avoid `float/real` data types.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean Sorry but i dont have access to database only access to select queries

Comment: @user580950 the quantity **4** is correct?, because the ID 1344 have 5 in quantity column.

Comment: @GastonF. Thanks for pointing it out actually the column name should be COUNT that means 3 bottles of [Size 15ml bottlle ] was ordered and so on as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the following:

- The **column** `options` always have **[...][...]** (two values).
- The **column** `quantity` will have the sum of the group.

Maybe this query will be useful (this works for Sql 2012-2008, but should work on 2005 too):

```
WITH temp AS(
SELECT 
  quantity,
  orderid,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(options,'][','.'),'[',''),']',''),1) AS first,
  PARSENAME(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(options,'][','.'),'[',''),']',''),2) AS second
FROM OrderDetails
),
concatenate_list AS (
  SELECT
    first AS options,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(x.orderid  AS VARCHAR)
           FROM temp x 
           WHERE x.first = y.first
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
    ) AS list
  FROM temp y
  GROUP BY y.first
UNION
  SELECT
    second as options,
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + CAST(x.orderid  AS VARCHAR)
           FROM temp x 
           WHERE x.second = y.second
           FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,''
    ) AS list
  FROM temp y
  GROUP BY y.second  
)
  SELECT 
    cl.options AS options,
    SUM(t.quantity) AS quantity,
    cl.list AS orderid
  FROM temp t
  LEFT JOIN concatenate_list cl ON cl.options = t.first
  GROUP BY cl.options,cl.list
UNION
  SELECT 
    cl.options AS options,
    SUM(t.quantity) AS quantity,
    cl.list AS orderid
  FROM temp t
  LEFT JOIN concatenate_list cl ON cl.options = t.second
  GROUP BY cl.options,cl.list
```

You try this **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2b1eb/1)**.

My example data is:

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetails(
options VARCHAR(100),
quantity int,
orderid int
 )

INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 15ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:12 mg Nicotnie]',1,1296)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 15ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:12 mg Nicotnie]',0,1391)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 15ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:0 mg Nicotnie]',1,1122)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 15ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:6 mg Nicotnie]',2,1196)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 30ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:5 mg Nicotnie]',1,4563)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 30ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:4 mg Nicotnie]',2,2123)
INSERT INTO OrderDetails VALUES('[Size 30ml bottlle][Nicotine Level:0 mg Nicotnie]',1,6754)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: it works great thanks for your help one question though what if there is no permission to create a temporary table "temp" is there any alternative to that ?

Comment: @user580950 Thanks, sorry I do not understand, Do not you can use `WITH temp ...` in your database?